# Why does ContinueWith pass the Task as the parameter

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, design-decisions

I have a `Task<T> t1`. I want to run another `Task t2` after `t1` completes. I choose to use the `.ContinueWith` method of `t1`.

```
void ThenFrob(Task<Frobber> t1) {
    t1.ContinueWith(frobber => frobber.Frob())
}
```

Except, I cannot do this, because the Action parameter of `Task<T>` is passed the `Task<T>`, rather than `T` itself. Instead, I have to take the result of the parameter passed into my action to interact with it.

```
void ThenFrob(Task<Frobber> t1) {
    t1.ContinueWith(frobberTask => {
        var frobber = frobberTask.Result;
        frobber.frob();
    });
}
```

If the point of ContinueWith is to add another action to the chain, why wouldn't the language designers have simply passed the result of the previous task? Or, in the case of a non-generic Task expected a parameterless action?

Comment: What is result of previous task, if task throw exception?

Comment: Thinking in line with non-parallel development or Promises, I would expect a different method signature for handling exceptions. ContinueWith implies to me that the previous task has completed, not errored.

Comment: BTW, I think it's a better practice to use `ContinueWith(async t=> { var result = await t ... })` rather than `.Result`, even for the smallest risk that someone would copy-paste the action into outer code where `.Result` might block the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContinueWith runs the delegate when the task enters the `task.IsCompleted == true` state. Not when it enters the `task.IsCompleted == true && task.IsFaulted == false && task.IsCanceled == false` state, a task that threw a exception or a task that was canceled both get "completed" but will not produce a result.

There are overloads you can pass in [`TaskContinuationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) like `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` to get behavior like you are describing, but it would be more complex to have a `Action<T>` overload for just that single enum option so they just use the general overload of `Action<Task<T>>` so you can use the same method if you are doing `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` or if you are doing `OnlyOnFaulted`.

Also there is still useful information in a `Task` object of a completed task, if you are using the [`AsyncState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.asyncstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property to pass metadata along if the completed task was not passed on to `ContinueWith` you would not have a way to get that data unless you used variable capture of a lambada expression.